# unable to run hadoop wordcount example?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running hadoop wordcount example in single node environment on ubuntu 12.04 in vmware.
i running the example like this:--

```
hadoop@master:~/hadoop$ hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount    
/home/hadoop/gutenberg/ /home/hadoop/gutenberg-output
```

i have input file at below location:

```
/home/hadoop/gutenberg
```

and location for output file is:

```
    /home/hadoop/gutenberg-output
```

when i run wordcount program i am getting following errors:--

```
 13/04/18 06:02:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area     
hdfs://localhost:54310/home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201304180554_0001       
13/04/18 06:02:10 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException       
as:hadoop cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory 
/home/hadoop/gutenberg-output already exists 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory 
/home/hadoop/gutenberg-output already exists at 

org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.j 
ava:137) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:887) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121) at   
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850) at  
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500) at  
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530) at 
org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:67) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68) 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139) at 
org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at   
org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156) hadoop@master:~/hadoop$ bin/stop-
all.sh Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated. stopping jobtracker localhost: stopping   
tasktracker stopping namenode localhost: stopping datanode localhost: stopping 
secondarynamenode    hadoop@master:~/hadoop$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the output file that already exists, or output to a different file.

(I'm a little curious what other interpretations of the error message you considered.)

Comment: yes output file already exist now i run successfully with different file but output file is not at the location i given

Comment: @Sandeepvashisth How are you looking at the file? I.e., what precise command(s)?

Comment: i can see directory with the following command:--                       bin/hadoop dfs -ls /home/hadoop                                              but not able to see with the explorer.

Comment: @Sandeepvashisth ... Unless your explorer is configured to mount HDFS filesystems somehow, this is unsurprising.

Answer (score 2):

Like Dave (and the exceptions) said, your output directory already exists.  You either need to output to a different directory or remove the existing one first, using:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /home/hadoop/gutenberg-output
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you've created your own .jar and is trying to run it, pay attention:**

In order the run your job, you had to have written something like this:

```
hadoop jar <jar-path> <package-path> <input-in-hdfs-path> <output-in-hdfs-path>
```

But if you take a closer look to your driver code, **you'll see that you have set `arg[0]` as your input and `arg[1]` as your output**... I'll show it:

```
FileInputFormart.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutFormart.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
```

But, hadoop is taking `arg[0`] as `<package-path>` instead of `<input-in-hdfs-path>` and arg[1] as `<input-in-hdfs-path>` instead of `<output-in-hdfs-path>`

So, in order to make it work, you should use:

```
FileInputFormart.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
FileOutFormart.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));
```

With `arg[1]` and `arg[2]`, so it'll get the right things! :)
Hope it helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

check whether there is 'tmp' folder or not.

hadoop fs -ls /

if you see the output folder or 'tmp' delete both (considering no running active jobs)

hadoop fs -rmr /tmp