# hadoop running application- ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I have written WordCount code of hadoop as an java application in eclipse to test hadoop for running applications, but when I try to run it as hdfs user, this error will appear:

```
./hadoop jar /home/masi/eclipse_workspace/WordCount_apacheSample/bin/test2.jar WordCountApacheSample /user/hdfs/wordCountInput /user/hdfs/wordCountOutput
13/10/02 17:14:50 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
13/10/02 17:14:50 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
13/10/02 17:14:50 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.net.ConnectException: Call From virtual-machine/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From virtual-machine/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1236)
    at WordCountApacheSample.main(WordCountApacheSample.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2100(Client.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1206)
    ... 29 more
```

although I have tested input and output paths with hdfs://localhost:9000/ , there is no difference!
BTW, I have studied many posts related to my problem but they were not useful

any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084998/unable-to-run-hadoop-wordcount-example

Comment: The exception is pretty clear about it, isn't it? `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From virtual-machine/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

finally I solved the problem by myself and decide to tell the reason here to help others :) the reason sounds somehow silly but the problem was this : the hadoop daemons were stop! my VM shut down suddenly and after restarting the VM, I had forgotten to start daemons(datanode, namenode,...) again!  so the reason of this problem is this: datanode and namenode and other daemons are not running.

Comment: I had a similar problem - made a 3 node VM system and when VM was not closed down normally, then I had to rebuild nodes - this was with ambari - I would like to have a script that "repairs" and get it up and running again, however so far it seems it will have to be manually -- huge waste of time

Answer (score 0):

if you discover that your hdfs is corrupt then you can do following:

```
sudo -su hdfs
hadoop  fsck /
hadoop  dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

... - then delete the corrupted files if any -using following:

```
      hadoop  fs -rmr -skipTrash <folder with your files>
      hadoop  fsck -files delete /
```

check status :

```
hadoop  fsck /
```

status should be HEALTHY after this - then manually restart everything in Ambari

I tried this on a small cluster and managed to get it up and running again after having similar error as mentioned above